# How to automatically add a current date to a column when another column is changed?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm working on a SharePoint list, and want to automatically add the current date to the attribute "Date X was implemented" when "Status" is changed to "implemented".

This is for SharePoint Designer 2010. I tried to solve the problem directly on the website with a calculated value and also in SharePoint Designer with a Workflow. Unfortunately, they both didn't work.

Here is the code for the calculated value I tried to use:

```
=IF( [Status] = implemented , Date X was implemented, "mm-dd-yyyy" )
```

And here is the SharePoint Designer Workflow I tried:

```
If Current Item:Status equals implemented
    Set Date X was implemented to Today
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a calculated column "Date X was implemented" in the list. Then use this formula:

> =IF([Status]="implemented",TODAY())

[image]
[image]

Another solution is creating workflow to achieve this:
[image]

You need to run the workflow for all the entries to update the value.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! Do you have another solution since we already have like 600 entries and a new column wouldn't work?